# Can I work in the US if I have a B visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, work, jamaican-citizens

Can I get lifeguard work with my B1-B2 visa?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: @Valentino Richards If that’s your real name, probably best not to publicise it on the Internet, especially given the nature of your question.

Comment: There's summer programs you can sign up to and work as a lifeguard for the summer on a J1 visa. Have a google.

Answer (score 6):

From [the US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html):

> An individual on a visitor visa (B1/B2) is not permitted to accept employment or work in the United States.

So it wouldn't be legal to work as a lifeguard on a B1/B2 visa.